# Derivative with respect to another function

Tags: calculus, reference-request, derivatives

I stumbled on this calculus problem here:

> Let $f(x) = \ln|\sec x + \tan x|$ and $g(x) = \sec x + \tan x.$ Find the fourth derivative of $g(x)$ taken with respect to $f(x)$
>
> A)$\\$ $f'(x)$
>
> B)$\\$ $f'(x)g(x)$
>
> C)$\\$ $g(x)$
>
> D)$\\$ $g'(x)$
>
> E)$\\$NOTA

**The answer to the question was C**

---

I understand how to find a function taken with respect with a derivative. For example, if I was trying to find the first derivative:

$$\frac{dg(x)}{df(x)} = \frac{dg(x)}{dx}*\frac{dx}{df(x)}$$

I would simply use the chain rule.

---

However, for subsequent derivatives, the two functions tend to get more messy, so I decided to look at the solution provided to see if there was an easier method.

Interestingly enough, the solution is:

> The first derivative simplifies as follows:

$$\frac{d(g(x))}{d(f(x))} = \frac{d(g(x))}{dx}*\frac{dx}{d(f(x))} = \frac{\sec^2(x) + \sec(x)\tan(x)}{\sec(x)} = g(x)$$
Thus all higher order derivatives will produce the same result, and the answer is $g(x) =$ C.

Is this conclusion true for any function taken with respect with another function? If so, if anyone could point me to a proof that would be also appreciated.

Comment: What does NOTA mean? It might be the correct answer...

Comment: @mickep None of the above. The solution states that the answer was C

Comment: I think in the solution the $*$ actually should be a division sign. The following step shows it.

Comment: @KittyL thanks for the mistake. Didn't catch it.

Comment: @Varun Iyer No problem.

Comment: I suppose that you noticed that $g(x)=e^{f(x)}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes I did. However, I thought it would still be messy when taking the fourth derivative.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici just saw your comment after I refreshed the comment thread!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
f = \ln|g(x)|\implies g(x) = \mathrm{e}^f
$$
thus
$$
g^{(4)} = \dfrac{d^4}{df^4}g = \dfrac{d^4}{df^4}\mathrm{e}^f = \mathrm{e}^f = g(x)
$$

Comment: So this conclusion cannot be made for all derivatives taken with respect to another function. This relationship was the reason then?

Comment: That is correct. The functional form of the exponential allowed for this. for example if it was $f = 2\ln|g(x)|$ then you would not get the relationship of $f^{(n)} = g(x)$ at all.

Comment: no problems :). I would also like to say thanks for your contributions/answers to the site also.